# x,y points at 95% confidence interval using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm pretty new to linux and want to use bash/awk to find the x points where y=.975 and y=.025 (95% confidence interval) which I can then use to give me the 'width' of my broad peak (the data kinda makes a bell curve shape).

This is the set of data with x,y values like so (NOTE: I intend to make dx increment much smaller resulting in much more/finer points):

```
       0                0
0.100893                0
0.201786                0
0.302679                0
0.403571                0
0.504464                0
0.605357                0
 0.70625                0
0.807143                0
0.908036                0
 1.00893                0
 1.10982                0
 1.21071                0
 1.31161                0
  1.4125       0.00173803
 1.51339        0.0186217
 1.61429        0.0739904
 1.71518         0.211295
 1.81607         0.725379
 1.91696          2.34137
 2.01786          4.69752
 2.11875          6.58415
 2.21964          6.06771
 2.32054          8.57593
 2.42143          11.7745
 2.52232          12.4957
 2.62321          13.0301
 2.72411          11.1008
   2.825          11.4504
 2.92589          12.6537
 3.02679          12.1584
 3.12768          11.0262
 3.22857          6.89166
 3.32946          5.88521
 3.43036          6.48794
 3.53125           5.0121
 3.63214          2.70189
 3.73304         0.914824
 3.83393         0.154436
 3.93482        0.0286775
 4.03571       0.00533823
 4.13661       0.00024829
  4.2375                0
 4.33839                0
 4.43929                0
 4.54018                0
 4.64107                0
 4.74196                0
 4.84286                0
 4.94375                0
 5.04464                0
 5.14554                0
 5.24643                0
 5.34732                0
 5.44821                0
 5.54911                0
```

First I want to normalise the y data so the values add up to a total of 1 (essentially to give me a probability of finding x at point y).

Then I want to determine the x-values that mark the start and end of the 95% confidence interval for the data set. The way I tackled this was to have a running sum of the column 2 y-values and then do `runsum/'sum'` in this way the values should fill up from 0-1 (see below). (NOTE: I used column -t to clean up the output a little)

```
sum=$( awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$2} END {print sum}' mydata.txt ) 
awk '{runsum += $2} ; {if (runsum!=0) {print $0,$2/'$sum',runsum/'$sum'} else{print $0,"0","0"}}' mydata.txt | column -t
```

This gives:

```
0         0           0            0
0.100893  0           0            0
0.201786  0           0            0
0.302679  0           0            0
0.403571  0           0            0
0.504464  0           0            0
0.605357  0           0            0
0.70625   0           0            0
0.807143  0           0            0
0.908036  0           0            0
1.00893   0           0            0
1.10982   0           0            0
1.21071   0           0            0
1.31161   0.00136559  8.92134e-06  8.92134e-06
1.4125    0.0259463   0.000169506  0.000178427
1.51339   0.159775    0.0010438    0.00122223
1.61429   0.552197    0.00360748   0.00482971
1.71518   1.2808      0.00836741   0.0131971
1.81607   2.20568     0.0144096    0.0276067
1.91696   3.29257     0.0215102    0.049117
2.01786   4.27381     0.0279206    0.0770376
2.11875   7.10469     0.0464146    0.123452
2.21964   9.56549     0.062491     0.185943
2.32054   11.3959     0.0744489    0.260392
2.42143   8.16116     0.0533165    0.313709
2.52232   9.08145     0.0593287    0.373037
2.62321   9.3105      0.0608251    0.433863
2.72411   10.8084     0.0706108    0.504473
2.825     10.4597     0.0683328    0.572806
2.92589   9.81763     0.0641382    0.636944
3.02679   9.06295     0.0592079    0.696152
3.12768   8.84222     0.0577659    0.753918
3.22857   10.285      0.0671915    0.82111
3.32946   8.37618     0.0547212    0.875831
3.43036   7.02052     0.0458648    0.921696
3.53125   4.82589     0.0315273    0.953223
3.63214   3.39214     0.0221607    0.975384
3.73304   2.2402      0.0146351    0.990019
3.83393   1.06194     0.00693761   0.996956
3.93482   0.350213    0.00228793   0.999244
4.03571   0.091619    0.000598543  0.999843
4.13661   0.0217254   0.000141931  0.999985
4.2375    0.00211046  1.37875e-05  0.999999
4.33839   0           0            0.999999
4.43929   0           0            0.999999
4.54018   0           0            0.999999
4.64107   0           0            0.999999
4.74196   0           0            0.999999
4.84286   0           0            0.999999
4.94375   0           0            0.999999
5.04464   0           0            0.999999
5.14554   0           0            0.999999
5.24643   0           0            0.999999
5.34732   0           0            0.999999
5.44821   0           0            0.999999
5.54911   0           0            0.999999
```

I guess I could use this to find the x points where y=.975 and y=.025 and solve my problem but do you guys know of a more elegant way and is this doing what I think it is?

Comment: Why awk specifically? I don't want to start a "my scripting language is better than yours" debate, but I think you might have an easier time doing this using something more along the line of perl, python or ruby...

Comment: To be honest, like I said I'm pretty new to scripting and it's just what I'm somewhat familiar with :)

Comment: Fair enough! I have done so many "not-to-be-done-in-bash" things myself, so why not? :D

Comment: Now, looking at your data... I don't know why, but the last column is not strictly increasing... Look around value "0.91495"...

Comment: I just saw this too! I think it's how I was doing the running sum. I'll edit the post, I think I may have corrected this...

Comment: The last column should be runsum/$sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 95% confidence interval is displayed at the bottom of the output:

```
$ awk -v "sum=$sum" -v lower=N -v upper=N '{runsum += $2; cdf=runsum/sum; printf "%10.4f %10.4f %10.4f %10.4f",$1,$2,$2/sum,cdf; print ""} lower=="N" && cdf>0.025{lower=$1} upper=="N" && cdf>0.975 {upper=$1} END{printf "lower=%s upper=%s\n",lower,upper}' mydata.txt
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.1009     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.2018     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.3027     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.4036     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.5045     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.6054     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.7063     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.8071     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    0.9080     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    1.0089     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    1.1098     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    1.2107     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    1.3116     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    1.4125     0.0017     0.0000     0.0000
    1.5134     0.0186     0.0001     0.0001
    1.6143     0.0740     0.0005     0.0006
    1.7152     0.2113     0.0014     0.0020
    1.8161     0.7254     0.0047     0.0067
    1.9170     2.3414     0.0153     0.0220
    2.0179     4.6975     0.0307     0.0527
    2.1187     6.5842     0.0430     0.0957
    2.2196     6.0677     0.0396     0.1354
    2.3205     8.5759     0.0560     0.1914
    2.4214    11.7745     0.0769     0.2683
    2.5223    12.4957     0.0816     0.3500
    2.6232    13.0301     0.0851     0.4351
    2.7241    11.1008     0.0725     0.5076
    2.8250    11.4504     0.0748     0.5824
    2.9259    12.6537     0.0827     0.6651
    3.0268    12.1584     0.0794     0.7445
    3.1277    11.0262     0.0720     0.8165
    3.2286     6.8917     0.0450     0.8616
    3.3295     5.8852     0.0384     0.9000
    3.4304     6.4879     0.0424     0.9424
    3.5312     5.0121     0.0327     0.9751
    3.6321     2.7019     0.0177     0.9928
    3.7330     0.9148     0.0060     0.9988
    3.8339     0.1544     0.0010     0.9998
    3.9348     0.0287     0.0002     1.0000
    4.0357     0.0053     0.0000     1.0000
    4.1366     0.0002     0.0000     1.0000
    4.2375     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    4.3384     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    4.4393     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    4.5402     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    4.6411     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    4.7420     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    4.8429     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    4.9437     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    5.0446     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    5.1455     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    5.2464     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    5.3473     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    5.4482     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
    5.5491     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000
lower=2.01786 upper=3.53125
```

To be more accurate, one would want to interpolate between adjacent values to get the 2.5% and 97.5% limits.  You mentioned, however, that your actual dataset has many more data points.  In that case, interpolation is superfluous complication.

How it works:

- `-v "sum=$sum" -v lower=N -v upper=N`

  Here we define three variables to be used by `awk`.  Note that we define `sum` here as an `awk` variable.  That allows us to use `sum` in the `awk` formulas without the complication of mixing shell variable expansion in with awk code.
- `runsum += $2; cdf=runsum/sum;`

  Just as you had it, we compute the running sum, `runsum`, and the cumulative probability distribution, `cdf`.
- `printf "%10.4f %10.4f %10.4f %10.4f",$1,$2,$2/sum,cdf; print ""`

  Here we print out each line.  I took the liberty here of changing the format to something that prints pretty.  If you need tab-separated values, then change this back.
- `lower=="N" && cdf>0.025{lower=$1}`

  If we have not previously reached the lower confidence limit, then `lower` is still equal to `N`.  If that is the canse and the current `cdf` is now greater than `0.025`, we set `lower` to the current value of `x`.
- `upper=="N" && cdf>0.975 {upper=$1}`

  This does the same for the upper confidence limit.
- `END{printf "lower=%s upper=%s\n",lower,upper}`

  At the end, this prints the lower and upper confidence limits.

Comment: Impressed. Nice presentation.